# How to combine two table rows with unmatched columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to query 'checkin_checkout' table for users attendance records for particular date range, with leave records from 'users_leave_status' table if users have applied for leaves within that particular data range.
I get following resultset, for eg., for date range - 2017-01-28 to 2017-01-29, after querying 'checking_checkout' table for two dates.

```
users_id | checkin_date | checkout_date | delayed_checkin remarks | early_checkout_remarks
1        | 2017-01-28   | 2017-01-28    | traffic jam             | NULL
2        | 2017-01-28   | 2017-01-28    | household               | NULL
3        | 2017-01-28   | 2017-01-28    | NULL                    | NULL
4        | 2017-01-28   | 2017-01-28    | traffic jam             | sick
1        | 2017-01-29   | 2017-01-29    | traffic jam             | NULL
3        | 2017-01-29   | 2017-01-29    | NULL                    | bored
4        | 2017-01-29   | 2017-01-29    | traffic jam             | NULL
```

Also I query 'users_leave_status' table to check if users have applied for dates for given date range, and I get following resultset :

```
users_id | leave_from | leave_to      | leave_type | leave_description
2        | 2017-01-29 | 2017-01-30    | Personal   | Trekking
5        | 2017-01-28 | 2017-01-30    | Sick       | Fever
```

Now I have these two resultsets for particular daterange, I need to combine those rows into one as follows :

```
users_id | checkin_date | checkout_date | delayed_checkin remarks | early_checkout_remarks | Leave Remarks
1        | 2017-01-28   | 2017-01-28    | traffic jam             | NULL | NULL
2        | 2017-01-28   | 2017-01-28    | household               | NULL | NULL
2        | 2017-01-29   | 2017-01-30    | NULL                    | NULL |Personal : Trekking
3        | 2017-01-28   | 2017-01-28    | NULL                    | NULL | NULL
4        | 2017-01-28   | 2017-01-28    | traffic jam             | sick | NULL
1        | 2017-01-29   | 2017-01-29    | traffic jam             | NULL | NULL
3        | 2017-01-29   | 2017-01-29    | NULL                    | bored| NULL
4        | 2017-01-29   | 2017-01-29    | traffic jam             | NULL | NULL
5        | 2017-01-28   | 2017-01-30    | NULL                    | NULL | Sick : Fever (Or something like this)
```

How do I combine these rows? All I know is UNION ALL and it is only for equal number of columns and with matching data-type columns. Please any solutions?

Comment: Can you show any SQL you've been using, it will help in working out where your having problems.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. Also, there is, presumably, a table of users somewhere, including their join date and leaving date.

Comment: @Strawberry Yes there is a 'users' table with all other details.. but just to be on point.. and it seems unnecessary, to mention it here.

Comment: You need union for this.